# Add two EditText values upon call of a button and display to a TextView using Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val addButton: Button? = null
    val editText1:EditText? = null
    val editText2:EditText? = null
    var resultTextView:TextView? = null

   addButton?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.addButton)
   editText1?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText1)
   editText2?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText2)
   resultTextView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultTextView)

    addButton?.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, resultTextView!!::class.java)

        var result = editText1?.text.toString() + editText2?.text.toString()


        resultTextView.text = result
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

I couldn't get result displayed on my `resultTextView`.

Comment: Intents are used for launching other activities and services, not for accessing widget properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how your code should look like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val addButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.addButton)
    val editText1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText1)
    val editText2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText2)
    val resultTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultTextView)

    addButton.setOnClickListener {
        val result = editText1.text.toString() + editText2.text.toString()
        resultTextView.text = result
    }
}
```

**P.S.** I suggest you to read more tutorials about Android basics before asking such simple questions.